# DocuSign- Electronically Seal(stamp) a PDF document using DocusignAPI

Tags: docusignapi

How to get a PDF document electronic sealed(stamped) in Docusign. We have requirement to send the PDF to a DocuSign API and get it sealed.? How to achieve this?